# Is there a flexc++ / bisonc++ that generates c++ code under Windows? Where do i download them from

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, bisonc++

I want to use c++ to write a flex/bison parser, but the flex/bison I installed can only use and generate c code.
I looked for a day yesterday and there are projects like flexc++ / bisonc++ in gitlab.
But this corresponds to the linux system, I need a Windows version

Comment: Which flex/bison did you install? Bison has been capable of producing C++ code for a long time.

Comment: @rici GNU Bison 2.4.1

Comment: That's very outdated. What about https://chocolatey.org/packages/winflexbison3

Comment: @rici Thank you in advance for telling me such great things about choco, and thank you for telling me how to install the latest version of win flex/bison. I will try to solve the problem, thank you!

Comment: @rici Unfortunately, although it is the latest version of flex/bison, it still cannot solve the problem.
Because the root cause of the problem is because I cannot use C++ code to write the description of bison rules, including bison generates program.tab.c instead of program.tab.cc or program.tab.cpp

Comment: did you tell bison to generate a c++ parser (`%language "c++"`)? Please read this tutorial from the bison manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/A-Simple-C_002b_002b-Example.html

Comment: @rici No . I didn't know there was such a usage.

Comment: @rici Thank You. I think we can work it out. Unfortunately, my mother confiscated my computer.

Comment: I don't think StackOverflow can help you with that problem. Good luck :-)